# Formatting a field using ToText in a Crystal Reports formula field

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to create a Crystal Reports formula field (to calculate the percentage change in a price) that will return "N/A" if a particular report field is null, but return a number to two decimal places using accounting format (negative numbers surrounded by parentheses) if it is not.

The closest I have been able to manage is this:

```
If IsNull({ValuationReport.YestPrice}) Then
    'N/A'
Else
    ToText({@Price}/{ValuationReport.YestPrice}*100-100, '###.00', 2)
```

However this represents negative numbers using a negative sign, not parentheses.

I tried format strings like '###.00;(###.00)' and '(###.00)' but these were rejected as invalid. How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are looking for `ToText(CCur(@Price}/{ValuationReport.YestPrice}*100-100))`

You can use `CCur` to convert numbers or string to Curency formats.  `CCur(number)` or `CCur(string)`

---

I think this may be what you are looking for,

`Replace (ToText(CCur({field})),"$" , "")`  that will give the parentheses for negative numbers

It is a little hacky, but I'm not sure CR is very kind in the ways of formatting

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isnull({uspRptMonthlyGasRevenueByGas;1.YearTotal})) = true then
   "nd"
else
    totext({uspRptMonthlyGasRevenueByGas;1.YearTotal},'###.00')
```

The above logic should be what you are looking for.